# If inside echo in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

This is my php code:

```
echo "<td><select name='Sucursal'  > 
<option value=''>Seleccione sucursal</option>
<option value='L1'>L1</option>  
<option value='L5'>L5</option>
<option value='L6'>L6</option>
<option value='PN'>PN</option>
<option value='MA'>MA</option>
</select></td>";
```

I'm "echoing" a select inside php, but I want to put this code inside each option value:

```
<option value="Male" <?php if($Gender == "Male") echo "selected"; ?>>Male</option>
```

My problem is I don't know how to put it inside the echo, If someone could help me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Don't output as a single monolithic string, then. Output each `<option>` separately and put your `selected` code in there. Do **NOT** try to embed logic for 7 different selects inside that one string. It'll be utterly disgustingly ugly, and make whoever has to maintain this code after you simply want to torture you to death with a wet spaghetti noodle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ternary operator](http://php.net//manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) is what you are looking for.

```
echo "
<td>
<select name='Sucursal'  > 
  <option value=''>Seleccione sucursal</option>
  <option ".($Sucursal == 'L1' ? 'selected' : '')." value='L1'>L1</option>  
  <option ".($Sucursal == 'L5' ? 'selected' : '')." value='L5'>L5</option>
  <option ".($Sucursal == 'L6' ? 'selected' : '')." value='L6'>L6</option>
  <option ".($Sucursal == 'PN' ? 'selected' : '')." value='PN'>PN</option>
  <option ".($Sucursal == 'MA' ? 'selected' : '')." value='MA'>MA</option>
</select>
</td>";
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a much cleaner method. Build an array of your options, loop through them to output the HTML, and while doing so use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to output selected property.

```
<?php

// Setup the key/value pair using an array
$opts = array(
    'L1' => 'L1',
    'L2' => 'L2',
    'L3' => 'L3'
    // Syntax: 'Key' => 'Option Label'
);

echo '<select name="select">';

// Loop through the array and output each key/value pair as an <option>
// Compare $Gender variable to each key in the loop, and output selected if so
foreach ( $opts as $key => $label ){
    echo '<option value="' . $key . '"' . ( $Gender == $key ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ) . '>' . $label . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [the concatenation](http://php.net//manual/en/language.operators.string.php) with [the ternary operator](http://php.net//manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to do what you want to do.